# Best practices for retrieving data scattered over multiple tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In the company I work with, we have a 3-layer architecture in our micro-services and the flow is like this:

```
Repository/DAO (entity) => Service (entity) => Controller (dto)
```

At the Controller level we map our entities to DTOs,

Now I am working on a search feature, and I need to perform a query with Spring Data JPA / QueryDSL that spans (joins) multiple entities (tables) in the database and must return only the fields needed to the UI.

For this purpose in the repository I create a query that return a DTO representing data needed by the UI.

And the query works perfectly and return the correct DTO,

However, some guys in my team told me that the DTOs are the Controller responsibility and they must be sent directly over the network and not through the app layers.

If I go with a different name like **`FooView`** or **`FooProjection`** should I :

1. make a extra mapping `View => DTO` in the controller layer ?
2. send it directly as `FooView`?

Or I shoud stick with my DTO at DAO layer ?

Answer (score 2):

Data Transfer Objects are used (among other things) so you don't send your entities over the network, and therefore create a dependency between the entity and the output of your API, this is why you map Entity->DTO in controller (or façade, if you have that layer).

Since you're not returning an entity in your case, the question is: do you need to do a mapping? If the `FooView` and `FooDTO` classes are going to be identical (as they most likely will), it might seem a bit useless and most likely will be. But there are at least two things to consider.

1. Consistency, meaning that your code will always map things to DTO in the controller, whether they are entities or views. The `FooProjection` name also distinguishes that this aggregates data, so it keeps the codebase cleaner.
2. Additional layer of abstraction. If you return `FooView` directly, the dependency is now on the query. This is less of a problem than having the dependency on an entity, but there might be a case where you decide to enrich `FooDTO` with additional data from a cache (for example) and suddenly `FooDTO = FooView + cachedata`.

So while sticking to a single `DTO` is one solution, with an additional class for the projection the flow would be as follows

```
FooDTO <= Controller <= FooProjection <= Service <= FooProjection <= DAO
```

> Or I shoud stick with my DTO at DAO layer ?

Cons of the extra mapping of course are: you'll have to create an additional class and possibly some amount of mapping code per such projection. If there's no advantage from the additional layer of abstraction and you are going to have 10s of extra classes, then you might want to keep your codebase cleaner and just use a single DTO. If you're going to have only a few projection classes, it's not much of a problem. They're not going to be of much use either though, so you can always defer to refactoring later on if you do want an additional layer of abstraction.

There's more discussion [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171457/what-is-the-point-of-using-dto-data-transfer-objects) about DTO usage and misusage.

Comment: So the main issue is when I would add some other fields from other sources ? or there can be other issues if I choose to send the data directly as `FooView` ?

Comment: There are no *real* issues, it's all about style and maintainability. You *can* return `FooView`, but since your teammates are telling you not to, you *should* convert to `FooDTO`. Then you get the advantages in my points 1. and 2. And it only "costs" you an extra class.

Comment: Even if you did return `FooView` now, it's still open to refactoring, so don't get too hung on the cache example I gave. You're writing enterprise code, don't be too amazed if there might be some code that isn't strictly necessary. It's still good to have a consistent codebase, even if it may result in (some) extra classes.

Answer (score 1):

There are two questions in your question.
Question 1: How to fetch scattered data accross tables?

Question 2: "some guys in my team told me that the DTOs are the Controller responsibility and they must be sent directly over the network and not through the app layers"

**Question 1 Answer**:
Since you are using hibernate I would focus on the pitfalls this creates. When using ORM very often people forget they are implicitly using SQL. A good aprach is to think backwards , what SQL you would like to have and then map it accordingly via ORM.

When collecting scattered data one major issue that may arrise from ORM usage would be effectivly joining two many tables which may have 2 effects:

- In case of Inner join, joining 4-5 tables especialy if nested  like table A join table B join table C where you have one to many A to B and one to many B to C would cause significant data duplication
- In case of **MULTIPLE LEFT JOIN** you have the potential of creating a problem known as Cartesian product.

So you more or less are left with couple of appriaches which can be used in different scenarios:

1. Lets say that you have a complex business process that may reuse the same data again and again within the same transaction. In this particular case you should not worry you are fetching to much as the overal gain you would have via Level 1 cache by far will surpass the negative effects of fetching too much.
   Level 1 caching within a transaction is very effective when dealing with repeatable reads.
2. Alternative aproach would be to write queries in order to fetch the scattered data accross the tables. There are some PROS and some CONS with this aproach.

PROS:

- You fetch only what you need.
- Performance is OK

CONS:

-The level of granularity is very fine grained. You may end up supporting a lot of queries

- The queries avoid Level 1 caching hibernate presents.
- Each query may cause flushing which may be negative when dealing with complex process / business transaction

3. Resolving the cartesian product issue if you are using activly your entities instead of your queries. You can use Collection Batching, or you can define how many levels your hibernate is allowed to fetch the collections.
   Another aproach here would be to use Fetch Strategy SELECT instead of JOIN. Such fetch strategy would be also more effective when it comes to hitting the cache because internaly hibernate will fetch aways by ID.

Now when you decide your aproach if it will be more ORM or if it will be more Query oriented. On top you can model your DTOs but this is secondary.

Hibernate also have a feature called projections so it may be possible to directly use the projections in your DTO later.

**Question 2 Answer:**

This answer presumes that you have dealt with fetching the scattered data via answer 1. In a big enough system there are well defined benefits to split your persistence model from your domain model even from your DTO model. Not every application is big and complex enough though to justify having all the three layers and all the boilerplate code that comes with it. Very often when doing a simple app a person measures the time and the resource you need to invest in order to keep all these layers. For a small enough application it may be justified to return your entities and hibernate projections as DTOs.

So the answer to your question is:

> It depends.

And by the way there is no such thing as DTO in the DAO layer :) But for small application it may be justified to re-use the objects accross the logical layers.

Answer (score 0):

I work on a .Net platform so different tech but the same issue.

`DataStore (sql<=>entity) => Service (entity) => Controller (entity<=>dto)`

Except our front end web app has been growing in size and taking on some of the functionality that was previously done by a thick client, that accessed the `Service (Entity)` layer directly.

Now its hard to take C# domain logic and ram that into a JavaScript web page. It also wants data in a different way to the thick client because its not reproducing the behaviour in full so much as complementing it or providing a lite version for the broader team to use.

For shifting data to the web app, it is pretty heavy weight to go through the Entity framework. It has all of the nice to haves like detecting which fields have changed, and a hierarchy of related nested objects. But the web app doesn't care the fields never change, and nested domain information if needed is in a separate query or is inlined producing a different perspective on the data.

The solution we came up with where Row Objects. They aren't entities and don't act like domain entities. They are readonly and produced by the database through a CQRS interface. We still have a different DTO type published in a DTO library so that the Controller and some of our other thick clients can share the same definition easily for trivial serialisation. The trick is that the Row Objects serialise to JSON identically to its DTO compatriot making conversion a snap. If they ever shift in the future we will probably realign them, but if push comes to shove, we can just map to the dto and serialise that.